# d3 it doesn't show any graphics

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to make a simple bar chart with D3, but on my web browsers page it's just white and it doesn't show any errors. I use XAMPP, Apache module is started. On my web browser, I do http://localhost/d3/project/test2.html to get to my project, but as I said it's just white. My CSV is just a country, population with 5 datasets. The files "API", "CHANGES", "d3", "d3.min", "LICENSE" and "README" in my d3 folder. If I go to elements, and go through the rectangles, it shows me for each "rect 0 * 0".This is my code:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
        const width = parseFloat(svg.attr("width"));
        const height = +(svg.attr("height"));
    
        //showing bar
        const render = data => {
        //xaxis
        const xScale  = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.population)])
        .range([0, width]);
    
        //yaxis
        const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(data.map(d => d.country))
        .range([0, height]);
        
        svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.country))
        .attr("width", d => xScale(d.population))
        .attr("height", yScale.bandWidth);
        };
    
        d3.csv("test.csv").then(function(data) {
        //convert
        data.forEach(d => {
            d.population = +d.population * 1000;
         });
        
        render(data)
         });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Testing2</title>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
       /* No style rules here yet */  
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
            <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you inspect the SVG, you should see rectangles without a height attribute: `yScale.bandWidth` should be `yScale.bandwidth`, I get a chart with your code if I do this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work either

Comment: yes the SVG doesn't show me a height attribute

Comment: check if `test.csv` file return data, maybe  your are requesting the wrong path.